# How to prevent stack overflow exception, when calling public static variables

Tags: c#, variables, nested

I've been coding in C# for about 3 years now, but have just started to get out of my comfort zone. I'm trying to develop a calculator for designing a basic roller coaster, but i'm running into the stackoverflowexception being thrown and terminating my program after I attempt the first section. The variables that I have found are the trouble are the "Time" Global class variable and the "Velocity" Global class variable. I have always attempted to, when at the main menu of my code, to press option number 1(the lift hill) and then do the math. right when i give the final value to calculate the solution to that section it throws the exception. I don't know if it's my initialization of the variables or the procedure of the calling of the class method. My code is posted below, thanks for the help.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  public static class Global
  {
    public static double Velocity
        {
        get { return Velocity; }
        set { Velocity = value; }
        }
    public static double Time
    {
        get { return Time; }
        set { Time = value; }
    }
    public static double MaxVel
    {
        get { return MaxVel; }
        set { MaxVel = value; }
    }
    public static double MaxAccel
    {
        get { return MaxAccel; }
        set { MaxAccel = value; }
    }
    public static double MaxPosG
    {
        get { return MaxPosG; }
        set { MaxPosG = value; }
    }
    public static double MaxNegG
    {
        get { return MaxNegG; }
        set { MaxNegG = value; }
    }
    public static double MaxLatG
    {
        get { return MaxLatG; }
        set { MaxLatG = value; }
    }
  }


  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double Straight_Time = 0, Brake_Time = 0, D_Time = 0, U_Time = 0, CurveUp_Time = 0, CurveDwn_Time = 0, UBTurn_Time = 0, BTurn_Time = 0, Helix_Time = 0, Helix_Velocity = 0, Helix_Time1 = 0, Helix_Time2 = 0;
        double Loop_Time = 0, arc1_Time = 0, arc2_Time = 0, arc3_Time = 0, Loop_Velocity = 0;
        const double M = 248.4472;// Cars Weight
        const double Mu = 0.08;//Friction Value
        const double G = 32.2;//Acceleration of gravity
        const double VelCheck = 146.667;
        const double AccelCheck = 100;
        const double GCheck_Pos = 5;
        const double GCheck_Neg = -1;
        const double GCheck_Lat = 10;
        double Power = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Roller Coaster Project Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        DrawingBoard:
        Console.WriteLine("Please Select a Calculation");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Lift Hill");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Hill Downwards");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Hill Upward");
        Console.WriteLine("4) Hill Upward Curve");
        Console.WriteLine("5) Hill Downward Curve");
        Console.WriteLine("6) Straight Section");
        Console.WriteLine("7) Unbanked Turn");
        Console.WriteLine("8) Banked Turn");
        Console.WriteLine("9) Brake");
        Console.WriteLine("10) Teardrop Loop");
        Console.WriteLine("11) Helix");
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Clear();
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Speed of the Lift Hill in MPH");
                double lift_Speed = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double lift_Convert = lift_Speed * 1.46667;
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Lift Hill Angle");
                double lift_Degree = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Lift Hill Height");
                double lift_Height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double lift_Distance = lift_Height / Math.Sin(lift_Degree);
                double lift_Time = lift_Distance / lift_Convert;
                Global.Time = Global.Time + lift_Time;
                Power = ((M * G * lift_Height) / lift_Time);
                Global.Velocity = lift_Speed;
                break;
            case 2: //this is for the downward facing hills
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Inital Hill Height");
                double D_Height_i = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Final Hill Height");
                double D_Height_f = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Hill Angle");
                double D_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double D_Vel = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity,2) + (2 * G * D_Height_i) + (2 * G * D_Height_f));
                double D_Fc = M * G;
                double D_DeltaVel = D_Vel - Global.Velocity;
                double D_Fn = D_Fc * Math.Acos(D_Angle);
                double D_Accel = (D_Fc * Math.Cos(D_Angle))/M;
                double D_Ff = Mu * D_Fn;
                double D_Deceleration = -(D_Ff / M);
                double D_DeltaHeight = D_Height_i - D_Height_f;
                double D_Distance = D_DeltaHeight / Math.Sin(D_Angle);
                double D_Vel2 = Math.Sqrt((2 * D_Deceleration * D_DeltaHeight) + Math.Pow(D_Vel, 2));
                if(VelCheck <= D_Vel2 || AccelCheck <= D_Accel)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if(D_Vel2 > Global.MaxVel)
                {
                    Global.MaxVel = D_Vel2;
                }
                D_Time = D_DeltaVel / (D_Accel - D_Deceleration);
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + D_Vel2;
                Global.Time = Global.Time + D_Time;
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Inital Hill Height");
                double U_Height_i = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Final Hill Height");
                double U_Height_f = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Hill Angle");
                double U_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double U_Vel = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) + (2 * G * U_Height_i) + (2 * G * U_Height_f));
                double U_DeltaVel = Global.Velocity - U_Vel;
                double U_Fc = M * G;
                double U_Fn = U_Fc * Math.Acos(U_Angle);
                double U_Accel = (U_Fc * Math.Cos(U_Angle)) / M;
                double U_Ff = Mu * U_Fn;
                double U_Deceleration = -(U_Ff / M);
                double U_DeltaHeight = U_Height_f - U_Height_i;
                double U_Distance = U_DeltaHeight / Math.Cos(U_Angle);
                double U_Vel2 = Math.Sqrt((2 * U_Deceleration * U_DeltaHeight) + Math.Pow(U_Vel, 2));
                if (VelCheck <= U_Vel2 || AccelCheck <= U_Accel)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (U_Vel2 > Global.MaxVel)
                {
                    Global.MaxVel = U_Vel2;
                }
                U_Time = U_DeltaVel / (U_Accel + U_Deceleration);
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + U_Vel2;
                Global.Time = Global.Time + U_Time;
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Hill Angle");
                double CurveUp_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Curve Radius");
                double CurveUp_Radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double CurveUp_Length = CurveUp_Angle * CurveUp_Radius;
                double CurveUp_Force = M * Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) / CurveUp_Radius;
                double CU_Fn = M * G;
                double CU_Ff = Mu * (CU_Fn + CurveUp_Force);
                double CU_G = ((CU_Fn + CurveUp_Force) / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double CurveUp_Deceleration = CU_Ff / M;
                double CU_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * CurveUp_Deceleration * CurveUp_Length))) / CurveUp_Deceleration;
                double CU_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * CurveUp_Deceleration * CurveUp_Length))) / CurveUp_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", CU_Quad1, CU_Quad2);
                int u = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (u)
                {
                    case 1:
                        CurveUp_Time = CU_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        CurveUp_Time = CU_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                double CU_Vel = Global.Velocity + (CurveUp_Deceleration * CurveUp_Time);
                if (GCheck_Pos <= CU_G)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if(CU_Vel > Global.MaxVel)
                {
                    Global.MaxVel = CU_Vel;
                }
                if (CU_G > Global.MaxPosG)
                {
                    Global.MaxPosG = CU_G;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + CurveUp_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + (CurveUp_Deceleration * CurveUp_Time);
                break;                case 5:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Hill Angle");
                double CurveDwn_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Curve Radius");
                double CurveDwn_Radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double CurveDwn_Length = CurveDwn_Angle * CurveDwn_Radius;
                double CurveDwn_Force = M * Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) / CurveDwn_Radius;
                double CD_Fn = M * G;
                double CD_Ff = Mu * (CD_Fn - CurveDwn_Force);
                double CD_G = ((CD_Fn - CurveDwn_Force) / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double CurveDwn_Deceleration = CD_Ff / M;
                double CD_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * CurveDwn_Deceleration * CurveDwn_Length))) / CurveDwn_Deceleration;
                double CD_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * CurveDwn_Deceleration * CurveDwn_Length))) / CurveDwn_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", CD_Quad1, CD_Quad2);
                int d = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (d)
                {
                    case 1:
                        CurveDwn_Time = CD_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        CurveDwn_Time = CD_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                double CD_Vel = Global.Velocity + (CurveDwn_Deceleration * CurveUp_Time);
                if (GCheck_Neg >= CD_G)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (CD_Vel > Global.MaxVel)
                {
                    Global.MaxVel = CD_Vel;
                }
                if (CD_G < Global.MaxNegG)
                {
                    Global.MaxNegG = CD_G;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + CurveDwn_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + (CurveDwn_Deceleration * CurveDwn_Time);
                break;
            case 6:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Length of the Straight Away");
                double Straight_Distance = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double Straight_Force = M * G;
                double Straight_Friction = -(Mu * Straight_Force);
                double Straight_Deceleration = Straight_Friction / M;
                double S_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity,2) - (2 * Straight_Deceleration * Straight_Distance)))/Straight_Deceleration;
                double S_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * Straight_Deceleration * Straight_Distance))) / Straight_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", S_Quad1, S_Quad2);
                int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (y)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Straight_Time = S_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Straight_Time = S_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + Straight_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + (Straight_Deceleration * Straight_Time);
                break;
            case 7:
                Console.WriteLine("What is The Angle of the turn?");
                double UBTurn_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double UBTurn_Theta = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("What is the Radius of the turn?");
                double UBTurn_Radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double UBTurn_Length = UBTurn_Theta * UBTurn_Radius;
                double UBTurn_Force = M * G;
                double UBTurn_Friction = -(Mu * UBTurn_Force);
                double UBTurn_Deceleration = UBTurn_Friction / M;
                double UBT_G = (UBTurn_Friction / M) *0.03107033639;  //converts to G's
                double UBT_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * UBTurn_Deceleration * UBTurn_Length))) / UBTurn_Deceleration;
                double UBT_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * UBTurn_Deceleration * UBTurn_Length))) / UBTurn_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", UBT_Quad1, UBT_Quad2);
                int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (a)
                {
                    case 1:
                        UBTurn_Time = UBT_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        UBTurn_Time = UBT_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                if (GCheck_Lat >= UBT_G)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (UBT_G < Global.MaxLatG)
                {
                    Global.MaxLatG = UBT_G;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + UBTurn_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + (UBTurn_Deceleration * UBTurn_Time);
                break;
            case 8:
                Console.WriteLine("What is The Angle of the turn?");
                double BTurn_Angle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double BTurn_Theta = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("What is the Radius of the turn?");
                double BTurn_Radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("What is the Bank of the turn?");
                double BTurn_Bank = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double BTurn_Length = BTurn_Theta * BTurn_Radius;
                double BTurn_Force = ((Math.Tan(BTurn_Bank) + Mu)/(1 - (Mu * Math.Tan(BTurn_Bank)))) * M * G;
                double BT_G = (BTurn_Force / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double BTurn_Friction = -(Mu * BTurn_Force);
                double BTurn_Deceleration = BTurn_Friction / M;
                double BT_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * BTurn_Deceleration * BTurn_Length))) / BTurn_Deceleration;
                double BT_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * BTurn_Deceleration * BTurn_Length))) / BTurn_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", BT_Quad1, BT_Quad2);
                int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 1:
                        BTurn_Time = BT_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BTurn_Time = BT_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                double BTurn_Vel = Global.Velocity + (BTurn_Deceleration * BTurn_Time);
                if (GCheck_Pos <= BT_G)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (BTurn_Vel > Global.MaxVel)
                {
                    Global.MaxVel = BTurn_Vel;
                }
                if (BT_G > Global.MaxPosG)
                {
                    Global.MaxPosG = BT_G;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + BTurn_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + (BTurn_Deceleration * BTurn_Time);

                break;
            case 9:
                double Brake_Final = 10;//ft/s
                double Brake_Mu = 0.91;
                double Brake_Force = M * G;
                double Brake_Friction = -(Brake_Mu * Brake_Force);
                double Brake_Deceleration = Brake_Friction / M;
                double Brake_Distance = (Math.Pow(Brake_Final,2) - Math.Pow(Global.Velocity,2))/(2 * Brake_Deceleration);
                double B_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * Brake_Deceleration * Brake_Distance))) / Brake_Deceleration;
                double B_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * Brake_Deceleration * Brake_Distance))) / Brake_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", B_Quad1, B_Quad2);
                int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (z)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Brake_Time = B_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Brake_Time = B_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                Global.Time = Global.Time + Brake_Time;
                Console.WriteLine("The Final Braking Speed Running into the Station is 10 ft/s");
                Console.WriteLine("The Brake Distance is {0}", Brake_Distance);
                break;
            case 10:
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Outer Radii");
                double outer_Loop = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Inner Radius");
                double inner_Loop = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                double loopTheta1 = 90;
                double loopTheta2 = 180;
                double loopTheta3 = 90;
                double arc1 = outer_Loop * loopTheta1;
                double arc2 = inner_Loop * loopTheta2;
                double arc3 = outer_Loop * loopTheta3;
                double arc1_Force = M * Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) / outer_Loop;
                double arc1_Fn = M * G;
                double arc1_Ff = Mu * (arc1_Fn + arc1_Force);
                double arc1_Deceleration = arc1_Ff / M;
                double Garc1 = ((arc1_Fn + arc1_Force) / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double arc1_Quad1 = (-Global.Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc1_Deceleration * arc1))) / arc1_Deceleration;
                double arc1_Quad2 = (-Global.Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc1_Deceleration * arc1))) / arc1_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", arc1_Quad1, arc1_Quad2);
                int l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (l)
                {
                    case 1:
                        arc1_Time = arc1_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        arc1_Time = arc1_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                if (GCheck_Pos <= Garc1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (Garc1 > Global.MaxPosG)
                {
                    Global.MaxPosG = Garc1;
                }
                Loop_Time = Loop_Time + arc1_Time;
                Loop_Velocity = Loop_Velocity + (arc1_Deceleration * arc1_Time);
                double arc2_Force = M * Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) / inner_Loop;
                double arc2_Fn = M * G;
                double arc2_Ff = Mu * (arc2_Fn - arc2_Force);
                double arc2_Deceleration = arc2_Ff / M;
                double Garc2 = ((arc1_Fn + arc1_Force) / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double arc2_Quad1 = (-Loop_Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc2_Deceleration * arc2))) / arc2_Deceleration;
                double arc2_Quad2 = (-Loop_Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc2_Deceleration * arc2))) / arc2_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", arc2_Quad1, arc2_Quad2);
                int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (m)
                {
                    case 1:
                        arc2_Time = arc2_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        arc2_Time = arc2_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                if (GCheck_Pos <= Garc2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (Garc2 > Global.MaxPosG)
                {
                    Global.MaxPosG = Garc2;
                }
                Loop_Time = Loop_Time + arc2_Time;
                Loop_Velocity = Loop_Velocity + (arc2_Deceleration * arc2_Time);
                double arc3_Force = M * Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) / outer_Loop;
                double arc3_Fn = M * G;
                double arc3_Ff = Mu * (arc3_Fn + arc3_Force);
                double arc3_Deceleration = arc3_Ff / M;
                double Garc3 = ((arc1_Fn + arc1_Force) / M) * 0.03107033639; //converts to G's
                double arc3_Quad1 = (-Loop_Velocity + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc3_Deceleration * arc3))) / arc3_Deceleration;
                double arc3_Quad2 = (-Loop_Velocity - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Loop_Velocity, 2) - (2 * arc3_Deceleration * arc3))) / arc3_Deceleration;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is the positive number? 1: {0} 2: {1}", arc2_Quad1, arc2_Quad2);
                int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (n)
                {
                    case 1:
                        arc3_Time = arc3_Quad1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        arc3_Time = arc3_Quad2;
                        break;
                }
                if (GCheck_Pos <= Garc3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Does not Meet the Saftey Constraints, Please Retry calculation.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Button to return to Menu");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Console.Clear();
                    goto DrawingBoard;
                }
                if (Garc3 > Global.MaxPosG)
                {
                    Global.MaxPosG = Garc3;
                }
                Loop_Time = Loop_Time + arc3_Time;
                Loop_Velocity = Loop_Velocity + (arc3_Deceleration * arc3_Time);
                Global.Time = Global.Time + Loop_Time;
                Global.Velocity = Global.Velocity + Loop_Velocity;
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The Final Velocity of This Section is {0} Feet Per Section", Global.Velocity);
        double Kinetic = (0.5) * M * Math.Pow(Global.Velocity, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Final Kinetic Energy of This Section is {0} Joules", Kinetic);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Would You Like to Continue the Roller Coaster?");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Yes");
        Console.WriteLine("2) No");
        int f = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch(f)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Clear();
                goto DrawingBoard;
            case 2:
                goto Final_Menu;
        }
        Final_Menu:
        Console.Clear();
        double min_Time = Global.Time / 60;
        double Percent = Power - Kinetic;
        Console.WriteLine("The Maximum Velocity Was {0}", Global.MaxVel);
        Console.WriteLine("The Maximum Acceleration Was {0}", Global.MaxAccel);
        Console.WriteLine("The Maximum Positive G's Were {0}", Global.MaxPosG);
        Console.WriteLine("The Maximum Negative G's Were {0}", Global.MaxNegG);
        Console.WriteLine("The Maximum Lateral G's Were {0}", Global.MaxLatG);
        Console.WriteLine("Total Ride Time Length is {0} Seconds or {1} Minutes", Global.Time, min_Time);
        Console.WriteLine("The Final Kinetic Energy is {0}, Which is {1}% of the original Amount of Energy", Kinetic, Percent);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Press Any Button To Exit Program...");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any reason to define everything static ????

Comment: it would allow each variable to have a static memory to it, so that it can be instanced during the program. It just makes the code a little bit faster because it doesn't have to go back and reread that variable again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your properties are defined like this:

```
public static double Velocity
{
     get { return Velocity; }
     set { Velocity = value; }
}
```

When this property is Got or Set, it refers to itself, which then refers to itself, which then refers to itself *ad infinitum* - or rather, until a stack overlow exception is raised.

I think you want the [auto-property syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb384054.aspx) instead:

```
  public static double Velocity { get; set; }
```

Or alternatively, use a backing field:

```
private static double velocity;

public static double Velocity
{
     get { return velocity; }
     set { velocity = value; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, that seemed to solve it, however when I now get through the first section and the press for the 5th section, when i get to the quadratic formula, it gives me NaN's. I use the menu for 5, the the angle is 60 and the radius of the turn is 10. would that have something to do with the Velocity and Time variables not initializing or getting called correctly?

Comment: @Starky_95 you should ask another question